# Score increasing by 2 when it should be increased by 1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a bullet and when it hits a target it should increment the score by 1. but the score is increasing by 2. the bullet is a capsule with a collider and rigibody and the target is a cylinder with a collider and rigibody

the code on the bullet

```
public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour {

 float lifespan = 2;

 void Start()
 {
     // destroy the bullet
     Destroy(gameObject, lifespan);
 }

 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)     //collider event
 {
     if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Score"))      
     {
         Score.score = Score.score + 1;
     }
 }
}
```

the score code

```
public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

 public static int score;        // The player's score.

 Text text;                      // Reference to the Text component.

 void Start()
 {
     // Set up the reference.
     text = GetComponent<Text>();

     // Reset the score.
     score = 0;
 } 

 void Update()
 {
     // Set the displayed text to the score value.
     text.text = "Score: " + score;
 }
}
```

Comment: Use debugger and check if method `OnTriggerEnter` is started twice.

Comment: Take a look at this please: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/ontriggerenter-is-called-twice-sometimes.95187/ Also, check if you have 2 colliders on any of the objects please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved this exact problem before but I searched for it to mark this as a duplicate but couldn't find it. It's probably deleted by the OP.

*There are 2 possible reasons why your score could update multiple times.*

**1**.Your script (`Bullet`) is attached to your GameObject multiple times. This is very likely the problem. It is very likely that it is attached to random empty GameObject.

**Fix:**

**A**.Check that `gameObject.AddComponent<Bullet>();` is not anywhere in any script in your project. The `AddComponent` will add new Bullet to your GameObject.

**B**.Search for duplicated script on GameObjects through the Editor.

Select your `Bullet` script, go to *Assets* --> *Find References in Scene*. It will show you every GameObject that has this script attached to it. Remove it from all of them except for your bullet GameObject.

[image]

**2**.You have more than one collider on the GameObject. Maybe a collider as a child. You must find a way to handle that. If this is the case, you can ignore the child colliders by putting them in a separate tag and checking it.

You are already checking the tags which is fine. Just change the tag of the child colliders to something else that is not *"Score"* so that `other.gameObject.CompareTag("Score")` will not be `true`.

Comment: Thanks, had script on the empty prefab object. that fixed it